# Can memcached be used for locking?

Tags: locking, memcached

`memcached` can be used for a caching static data which reduces database lookup and typically does `memcached.get(id)` and `memcached.set(id)`.

However is it fine to use this for locking mechanisms?  Does `memcache.set` and `memcached.get` always give the data if it is present or will it just return None if the request is taking too much time?

I want to avoid concurrent access to a particular resource identified by a `id` and I use this logic:

```
def access(id):
    if memcache.get(id):
        return access
    else:
        memcache.set(id)
        return true
```

If any user tries to access that resource, if `memcache.get(id) = username` returns a value we decline the access else we do `memcache.set(id) = username` to stop subsequent access and allow access for the current user.

Is it fine to using `memcached` like this? Will `set` and `get` actually give the data if its available regardless of the time it takes or does it give best possible result in the least possible time from whatever I have found (for example: [Guaranteed memcached lock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6538938/452102)) so far is of the former category and might not work for locking thought it might work 99% of the time.

Can anyone clarify and if there are alternative locking mechanisms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone intersted in this, I have created a thread on Memcache Github at [Will memcached work reliably for implementing a locking mechanism?](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/issues/163). It explains some of the common caveats using `get` and `set` and how to avoid that using `add`. Some blogs also explain this problem if you can search for `distributed locking` using `memcache` on your favorite search engine.

There is also a related question [Memcached, Locking and Race Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608902/memcached-locking-and-race-conditions) which might help on getting more clarity on memcache race conditions.

Here is more discussions on this at the Memcache Forum:

[Thread 1](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/memcached/Szb0tsR72HQ/discussion) and [Thread 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memcached/thhwPzg0O9U/discussion)